# Finding the convergence radius of a power series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, power-series, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ be a power series. Prove that
>
> 1. If $\large \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_ns^n=0,s>0$, then the power series above converges absolutely for $|x|<s$.
> 2. Conclude that
>      $$R=\sup A,$$
>      where $R$ is the radius of convergence of the power series and
>      $$A=\left\{x\geq 0|\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_nx^n=0\right\}$$

The (2) item follows straightforward from the (1) item, but here is the trouble, how can we prove (1)?

Comment: Maybe compare the power series for points with $|x|<s$ with the given series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be such that $|x|\lt t$. Notice that for $n$ large enough, we have 
$$|a_nx^n|\leqslant |a_n t^n|\left|\frac xt\right|^n\leqslant \left|\frac xt\right|^n,$$
and the series $\sum_nr^n$ converges for $r\in (0,1)$.